# What Are the Origins of Chocobos From the Final Fantasy Universe?

Tags: history-of, animals, final-fantasy

As any players / fans of the famous video game franchise **Final Fantasy** can tell you. Chocobos are a big part of the Final Fantasy universe, well maybe not such a big part as they are just a necessity to the universe's workforce.

[image: here is a chocobo and it is the cutest thing ever]

Chocobos are similar to horses in the way that

1. **They are beasts of burden**
2. **They are ride-able**

But I would like to know is there a origin story for the chocobo? Or any ancient history involving chocobo-like creatures that could have influenced their creation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocobo#Character_design

Comment: Ostrich? - also this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plk35VYDKZE :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [chocobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocobo#Character_design) was created and designed by Koichi Ishii, a video game director who worked on various Final Fantasy titles. The chocobo appears remarkably similar to and was **likely inspired** by the prehistoric bird Gastornis. –Wiki

[Gastornis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastornis) is an extinct genus of large flightless birds that lived during the late Paleocene and Eocene epochs of the Cenozoic era. –Wiki

[image]

<sub>Life restoration of G. steini (now G. gigantea), 1917</sub>

Other possibilities include *Kyorochan*, a character in television advertisements for Morinaga & Company's chocolate candy, and Hayao Miyazaki's *Horseclaws*, which were inspired by the Gastornis.